# Send mail async not working

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5

> i am trying to send email async method , but no email sent

https://dotnetfiddle.net/oFVtN2

Comment: Glad to see that people (including me) can get help even if 6 admin don't like the way the question get asked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of your 'fire and forget', you are disposing of the mail message immediately; that may be affecting you.  Also, you're not disposing of the mail client.  You should put the entire operation into the "fire and forget", including the creation and disposal of SmtpClient.  Something more like this:

```
FireAndForgetTask(async cancellationToken =>
{
                using(var smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = "myhost",
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = false,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail", "mypass"),
                    Timeout = 50000
                })
                {          
                    using (var message = new MailMessage("myemail", destMail)
                    {
                        Subject = subject,
                        Body = mailBody,
                        IsBodyHtml = html           
                    })
                    {
                       await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: i am new at this, what i need to fix?

Comment: what do you mean ? "you are disposing of the mail message immediately", the fix is to put             BackgroundTaskRunner.FireAndForgetTask(async () =>
 on all func?

Comment: The problem is that the FireAndForget method runs on a background thread, so when you call it, execution continues even though that work isn't done yet.  So the sequence of events in your pastebin is 1) Create MailMessage in the using block; 2) CallFireAndForget; 3) Exit the using block and dispose the message; 4) Call SendMailAsync

Comment: A related problem is that SendMailAsync is asynchronous, so when HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundTask gets to it, the call to QueueBackgroundTask will return before SendMailAsync finishes.  I'm not sure which, if either, of these is the problem, but I would suggest reading up more on async and threading, and adding some logging, so you can understand the sequence of your code, which is probably not what you are expecting.

Comment: This diagram may be useful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443.aspx#Anchor_2